# Rendering data on the same template from different models

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, bootstrap-cards

I want to render data on the same template(shared template) from different models
I have the following models in **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    Custom user model to support role-based authentication.
    """

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('client', 'Client'),
        ('staff', 'Staff'),
        ('admin', 'Admin'),
    ]
    
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default='client')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    # Specify unique related_name for groups and user_permissions
    user_groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='custom_user_groups',
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='groups',
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to.',
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='custom_user_permissions',
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
    )

    def get_user_type_display(self):
        """
        Display the user type in a more readable format.
        """
        return dict(CustomUser.USER_TYPE_CHOICES)[self.user_type]

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'






class GarbageCollectionRequest(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a request for garbage collection made by a client.
    """

    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='garbage_requests')
    request_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    request_details = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    collection_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Request #{self.pk} - {self.client.username} - {self.address}"
```

And my class-based **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import CustomUser, GarbageCollectionRequest, CollectionAssignment, GarbageCollectionLog, Payment


class CustomUserListView(ListView):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'admin_dash.html'


class GarbageCollectionRequestListView(ListView):
    model = GarbageCollectionRequest
    template_name = 'garbage/admin_dash.html'
    ordering = ('-request_date')
```

my **admin_dash.html** which i have extended from **main.html**

```
{% extends 'garbage/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Admin Dashboard {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="main--content">
    <br><br>
    <div class="overview">
        <div class="title">
            <h2 class="section--title">Overview</h2>
            <select name="date" id="date" class="dropdown">
                <option value="today">Today</option>
                <option value="lastweek">Last Week</option>
                <option value="lastmonth">Last Month</option>
                <option value="lastyear">Last Year</option>
                <option value="alltime">All Time</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card card-1">
                <div class="card--data">
                    <div class="card--content">
                        <h5 class="card--title">Requests</h5>
                        <h1>152</h1>
                    </div>
                    <i class="ri-user-2-line card--icon--lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card--stats">
                    <span><i class="ri-bar-chart-fill card--icon stat--icon"></i>65%</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-up-s-fill card--icon up--arrow"></i>10</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill card--icon down--arrow"></i>2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-2">
                <div class="card--data">
                    <div class="card--content">
                        <h5 class="card--title">Assigned</h5>
                        <h1>1145</h1>
                    </div>
                    <i class="ri-user-line card--icon--lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card--stats">
                    <span><i class="ri-bar-chart-fill card--icon stat--icon"></i>82%</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-up-s-fill card--icon up--arrow"></i>230</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill card--icon down--arrow"></i>45</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-3">
                <div class="card--data">
                    <div class="card--content">
                        <h5 class="card--title">Completed</h5>
                        <h1>102</h1>
                    </div>
                    <i class="ri-calendar-2-line card--icon--lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card--stats">
                    <span><i class="ri-bar-chart-fill card--icon stat--icon"></i>27%</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-up-s-fill card--icon up--arrow"></i>31</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill card--icon down--arrow"></i>23</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-4">
                <div class="card--data">
                    <div class="card--content">
                        <h5 class="card--title">Pending</h5>
                        <h1>15</h1>
                    </div>
                    <i class="ri-hotel-bed-line card--icon--lg"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card--stats">
                    <span><i class="ri-bar-chart-fill card--icon stat--icon"></i>8%</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-up-s-fill card--icon up--arrow"></i>11</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-arrow-down-s-fill card--icon down--arrow"></i>2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="doctors">
        <div class="title">
            <h2 class="section--title">Clients</h2>
            <div class="doctors--right--btns">
                <select name="date" id="date" class="dropdown doctor--filter">
                    <option >Filter</option>
                    <option value="free">Free</option>
                    <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
                </select>
                <button class="add"><i class="ri-add-line"></i>Add Client</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="doctors--cards">

            <!--Rendering clients ---->
            {% for user in custom_users %}
                
                    <a href="#" class="doctor--card">
                        <div class="img--box--cover">
                            <div class="img--box">
                                <img src="" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="free">Free</p>
                    </a>
                
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="recent--patients">
        <div class="title">
            <h2 class="section--title">Recent Requests</h2>
            <button class="add"><i class="ri-add-line"></i>Add Request</button>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Date in</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Assigned</th>
                        <th>Collection Date</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--Rendering requests ---->
                    {% for request in object_list %} 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ request.client.username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.request_date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.address }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.phone }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.is_assigned }}</td>
                            <td class="pending">{{ request.collection_date }}</td>
                            <td><span><i class="ri-edit-line edit"></i><i class="ri-delete-bin-line delete"></i></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
            
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

rendering requests in a table format am satisfied with it at the moment:

```
<div class="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Date in</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Assigned</th>
                        <th>Collection Date</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--Rendering requests ---->
                    {% for request in object_list %} 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ request.client.username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.request_date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.address }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.phone }}</td>
                            <td>{{ request.is_assigned }}</td>
                            <td class="pending">{{ request.collection_date }}</td>
                            <td><span><i class="ri-edit-line edit"></i><i class="ri-delete-bin-line delete"></i></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
            
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

NB: Am not getting any errors
I added a method on CustomUser model

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['custom_users'] = CustomUser.objects.all()
        return context
```

to return data that is passed to the template and modified the part i want to render the clients in the template using bootstrap like cards:

```
<div class="doctors--cards">

            <!--Rendering clients ---->
            {% for client in custom_users %}
                {% if client.user_type == 'client' %}
                    <a href="#" class="doctor--card">
                        <div class="img--box--cover">
                            <div class="img--box">
                                <img src="" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="free">Free</p>
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

but i seen not to archive that< any advise and suggestions how i acn go about?
I have also added a screenshot of the progress so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added a method on CustomUser model

The method `get_context_data` has to be used in a class based view, not in a model. You should add it to your `GarbageCollectionRequestListView`. Then `custom_users` variable will be available in your template (but only for the garbage collection request list).

In order to use the same template for garbage collection, you'll have to modify `CustomUserListView` like this :

```py
class CustomUserListView(ListView):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'admin_dash.html'
    context_object_name = 'custom_users'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = GarbageCollectionRequest.objects.all()
        return context
```

`context_object_name` property indicates the name to provide to the users list variable.

Comment: Its happening now really appreciate

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Just as a follow-up question, why would you need to views to display the same shared template ?

Comment: I Am creating something like a dashboard while pulling data from different views. Am also trying to do modular(separate templates) like building then I include them on one template to see if i can have the same results